# Installation of RQuantLib

Tags: r, install.packages

I tried to install RQuantLib from RStudio, but it has given me problems.

I updated my R version to 3.3.1 and tried to use the usual way of installing a package (`install.packages("RQuantLib")`) as recommended on the webpage of the author (http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rquantlib.html). However, it gave the following error message :

> Warning in install.packages :
>    package ‘RQuantLib’ is not available (for R version 3.3.1)

I tried installing it on different computers too, but I got the same error message.

Does anyone else experience the same problem or has any idea what could have gone wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Which OS? Tell us your `sessionInfo()`

Comment: R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 14393)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.1

Answer (score 10):

You are on Windows per your comment.  As per this section of the [README.md](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rquantlib/blob/master/README.md)

> #### Windows Binaries
>
> Starting with release 0.4.3, binaries are provided via the ghrr drat repo and can be installed as
>
> `R> drat::addRepo("ghrr")       #  maybe use 'install.packages("drat")' first`
> `R> install.packages(RQuantLib)`

you can install a pre-built Windows binaries -- which I just updated for QuantLib 1.8.1 -- from this non-CRAN repo.

*Edit:*  Apparently one now has to say `type="binary"` even on Windows.  Here is a log from a virtual machine I keep:

```
R> drat::addRepo("ghrr")
R> options("repos")
$repos
                          CRAN                           ghrr 
 "https://cloud.r-project.org" "https://ghrr.github.io/drat/" 

R> install.packages("RQuantLib", type="binary")
Installing package into c:/opt/R-library
(as lib is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://ghrr.github.io/drat/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/RQuantLib_0.4.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 7993848 bytes (7.6 MB)
downloaded 7.6 MB

package RQuantLib successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\[redacted]\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpAHvBmo\downloaded_packages
R>
```

I'll update the `README.md` web page.

Comment: I tried this again on two computers and even an online version of RStudio, but still the same error message. Anyhow, I believe that the problem is on my side. Thank you for your help anyways

Comment: I edited my answer -- apparently, one now needs to add `, type="binary"` to the `install.packages()`.  I added the output from a successful installation in a Windows (virtual) machine.

Comment: That was the intent all along so thanks to you for alerting me to the need for `type="binary"` !

Comment: Now, this being StackOverflow, please consider "accepting" (click on tickmark only you as the person asking the question sees) and/or "upvoting" (click on upward-facing triangle).  You get points for accepting too.